# Create lists from arrays from elements at corresponding indices

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to java 8. Just wondering how would I do below operation using java 8 streams. Any suggestions

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3};
    Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[]{4, 5, 6};
    Integer[] arr3 = new Integer[]{7, 8, 9};

    for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
        System.out.println(listFromIndex(arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i]));
    }
}

private static List<Integer> listFromIndex(Integer e, Integer e1, Integer e2) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(e) ;
    list.add(e1) ;
    list.add(e2) ;
    return list;
}
```

Output :

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the arrays have the same length you can use this:

```
List<Integer[]> arrays = Arrays.asList(arr1, arr2, arr3);
IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> arrays.stream().map(a -> a[i]).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This creates a list containing all arrays. After that it creates a stream iterating over all arrays and collects the new arrays.

This will print the following result:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

If you have arrays with different lengths you can use something like this:

```
Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3};
Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[]{4, 5};
Integer[] arr3 = new Integer[]{7};

List<Integer[]> arrays = Arrays.asList(arr1, arr2, arr3);
IntStream.range(0, arrays.stream().mapToInt(a -> a.length).max().orElseThrow())
        .mapToObj(i -> arrays.stream().map(a -> i < a.length ? a[i] : null).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This uses the length of the largest array and checks `i` before collecting the resulting arrays.

The result will be this:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, null]
[3, null, null]
```

Comment: thanks, I just  added max().getAsInt() and applied non null filter before collecting to fit my requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the arrays are of the same length, you can do it as:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> listFromIndex(arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i]))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Would be even better when replacing the misleadingly named `listFromIndex` with, e.g. `Arrays.asList(arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i])`.